# How is web cache poisoning possible?

Tags: web-application, http, web

There is a lot of literature out there about this, and I've read many of it, but one question I couldn't rectify is this. Consider this quote from [netsparker.com](https://www.netsparker.com/blog/web-security/web-cache-poisoning-introduction/):

> **Reflected unkeyed headers:**
> If the application directly reflects the value of a certain unkeyed header in the response, it opens an easy avenue to cache poisoning. Because the header is unkeyed, its value is not part of the cache key and plays no part in deciding about cache hits. If the attacker sends a request where only this header is maliciously modified, the response to this request will be cached, complete with the malicious payload (targeting, for example, a cross-site scripting vulnerability). Users subsequently requesting content that matches the same cache key will receive the malicious version from the cache.

If the request sent by the attacker contains a malicious unkeyed header, wouldn't the cache simply send back a cached response without the request ever reaching the back-end server, because the cache doesn't look at the malicious header itself and the request matches with some cache key in the cache? In that situation, can the attacker ever reach the back-end server without changing some keyed component in the request as well?

Comment: Your arguments are based on the assumption that the cache contains already a relevant entry and so the response will be taken from the cache. What you cite instead is based on the assumption that the cache does not contain yet such an entry and thus the server need to be asked.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that makes a lot of sense. So the attack is only possible if the cache doesn't yet contain a valid entry for the request. My assumption is that such situations are rare if the resource faces sufficient traffic from users because the cache quickly gets refreshed if it expires. Is that assumption wrong?

Comment: *"Is that assumption wrong?"* - it depends a lot on the use case, on cache eviction policies, if it is about a common URL or an attacker constructed URL etc. And even with lots of requests answered from cache the attacker could request the resource again and again and has a high chance to hit the cache exactly when the resource has expired and need to be refreshed.